# How to change the maven repository jar name?

Tags: java, maven, jdbc

I have made a dependency in pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <tibero-version>5.0</tibero-version>
</properties>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.tmax.tibero</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibero5-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${tibero-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I copied tibero5-jdbc.jar to the folder `~/.m2/repository/com/tmax/tibero/tibero5-jdbc/5.0/`

However, maven just looks up tibero5-jdbc-5.0.jar.
How can I correct this so that it looks for the JAR in that folder?

Comment: copy it to the right Name tibero5-jdbc-5.0.jar

Comment: that name(tibero5-jdbc.jar) was made by name rule.

Comment: tibero reference just tibero5-jdbc.jar in my thought.

Comment: `is made by name rule`  --> should be by  maven rule. use mvn install:install-file ....

Answer (score 1):

Maven will not be able to find the dependency if you just copy a jar like that, it needs to have its associated pom descriptors.

Do maven manual [install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html)

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=< jarfiledirectory >\tibero5-jdbc-5.0.jar -DgroupId=com.tmax.tibero
-DartifactId=tibero5-jdbc -Dversion=5.0 -Dpackaging=jar